# Plot SharePoint List Data on Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint, leaflet, geojson

I have a SharePoint list with a location column that contains latitude and longitude separated by a comma.
I am attempting to plot these points on a leaflet map embedded in a webpart but have been unsuccessful.
I have my map set up and rendering. I can plug in my own plot points; however, I cannot figure out how to get the list data into my leaflet map html for plotting.
I have read about using REST calls or retrieving the information and converting to GeoJSON but have failed.
I was thinking about having a workflow generate a csv file on item creation in order to use but would rather just pull it off the SharePoint list directly.

I've tried to incorporate this into the leaflet html.

```
        function plotMap(){
$.ajax({ 
    url: "SITEURL/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Open Permits')/items", 
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){  
                  var mapMarker = "{icon:"some image url.replace";
                  var latlng = item. Location.split(",");
                  L.marker([latlng[0],latlng[1]],mapMarker).addTo(map).bindPopup(item.Equipment);
        });
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}
```

I guess one, I don't know where I should drop this in the map file and two if it's the correct method for getting the list data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to retrieve list items first and then run a function to plot your points.

```
var items = [];

function getSP() {   
    var scriptBase = siteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptBase + "MicrosoftAjax.js").then(function (data) {
        return $.getScript(scriptBase + "SP.Runtime.js");
    }).then(function (data) {
        return $.getScript(scriptBase + "SP.js");
    }).then(function (data) {
        retrieveListItems()
      });
}

function retrieveListItems() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    console.log(clientContext)
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Open Permits');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' +
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Query></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);    
    clientContext.load(collListItem);    
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function valueOrNone(oListItem, value) {
    try {
        finalValue = oListItem.get_item(value).get_lookupValue();
    } catch (err) {
        finalValue = '';
    }
    return finalValue;
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {    
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
      
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();    
        var item = {};
        item['ID'] = oListItem.get_id();
        item['Equipment'] = valueOrNone(oListItem, 'Equipment');
        item['Location'] = valueOrNone(oListItem, 'Location');
        items.push(item)
    }
    
    console.log(items)
    plotMap()
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function plotMap() {      
 items.forEach(x => {
  var mapMarker = "{icon:"some image url.replace";
  var latlng = x.Location.split(","); 
  L.marker([latlng[0],latlng[1]],mapMarker).addTo(map).bindPopup(x.Equipment);
  });
}
```